# Android FAB animation doesn't work properly

Tags: android, android-animation, floating-action-button

I'm trying to `rotate` `Floating Action Button`, but I can see whether very fast animation or nothing.

Here's `res/anim/rotate.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:duration="1600"
android:fromDegrees="0"
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%"
android:fillAfter="true"
android:toDegrees="180" />
```

After the testing it with simple `TextView` I've found, that it worked.

And this is  how I try to start animation.

```
final Animation rotate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.rotate);
final FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            fab.startAnimation(rotate);

        }
    });
```

All what  can I see is standard `onClick`  animation of the `FAB` (or very fast animation, if I use scale one)

What can I do with it?

Answer (score 1):

Declaring the animation from code helped me. Try something like this:

```
ViewCompat.animate(fab).rotation(180).setDuration(1600).start();
```

It seems that the clicked FAB has another animation to proceed and it overrides your animation.